# Intersection between a side of rotated rectangle and axis

Tags: geometry

There is a rectangle with center in 0,0 position of decart coordinate system. I know the rectangle width, height and an angle of rotate. How can I find coordinates of intersection point (and length) between x/y axis and rectangle sides?

We need to find A1 and B1:
[image: Please, look at this picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rotation angle $\alpha$ is between $0°$ and $90°$ then:
$$
A1=\min\left({A\over\cos\alpha},\ {B\over\sin\alpha}\right),\quad
B1=\min\left({B\over\cos\alpha},\ {A\over\sin\alpha}\right).
$$

Comment: @Arentino, thanx!!! Can you explain this formula?

Comment: If $\alpha<90°$ then $A1$ is formed by the intersection between the $x$-axis and the bottom or left side of rectangle. The bottom side (produced if needed) intersects the $x$-axis at $x=B/\sin\alpha$, while the intersection with the left side is at $x=A/\cos\alpha$. You just need to pick the smallest value to have the right result. A similar reasoning can be made for $B1$.